# Docker experimental mode does not support windows containers (any more?)

Tags: windows, docker, containers

I used to run windows and linux containers in parallel on the same computer using the docker "experimental" feature. But for some reason, I cannot get it to work on a newly set-up computer any more. The host runs Windows 10, 22H2.

I have docker-desktop installed, version 24.0.2. I can manually switch between linux and windows containers (using both the GUI and the CLI) and run corresponding containers. Normally, to get both working at the same time, I switch to windows containers and enable experimental mode (and make sure the service is restarted). But it doesn't help.

output of `docker info`:

```
Client:
 Version:    24.0.2
 Context:    default
 Debug Mode: false
 Plugins:
  buildx: Docker Buildx (Docker Inc.)
    Version:  v0.11.0
    Path:     C:\Program Files\Docker\cli-plugins\docker-buildx.exe
  compose: Docker Compose (Docker Inc.)
    Version:  v2.19.1
    Path:     C:\Program Files\Docker\cli-plugins\docker-compose.exe
  dev: Docker Dev Environments (Docker Inc.)
    Version:  v0.1.0
    Path:     C:\Program Files\Docker\cli-plugins\docker-dev.exe
  extension: Manages Docker extensions (Docker Inc.)
    Version:  v0.2.20
    Path:     C:\Program Files\Docker\cli-plugins\docker-extension.exe
  init: Creates Docker-related starter files for your project (Docker Inc.)
    Version:  v0.1.0-beta.6
    Path:     C:\Program Files\Docker\cli-plugins\docker-init.exe
  sbom: View the packaged-based Software Bill Of Materials (SBOM) for an image (Anchore Inc.)
    Version:  0.6.0
    Path:     C:\Program Files\Docker\cli-plugins\docker-sbom.exe
  scan: Docker Scan (Docker Inc.)
    Version:  v0.26.0
    Path:     C:\Program Files\Docker\cli-plugins\docker-scan.exe
  scout: Command line tool for Docker Scout (Docker Inc.)
    Version:  0.16.1
    Path:     C:\Program Files\Docker\cli-plugins\docker-scout.exe

Server:
 Containers: 0
  Running: 0
  Paused: 0
  Stopped: 0
 Images: 2
 Server Version: 24.0.2
 Storage Driver: windowsfilter
  Windows:
 Logging Driver: json-file
 Plugins:
  Volume: local
  Network: ics internal l2bridge l2tunnel nat null overlay private transparent
  Log: awslogs etwlogs fluentd gcplogs gelf json-file local logentries splunk syslog
 Swarm: inactive
 Default Isolation: hyperv
 Kernel Version: 10.0 19045 (19041.1.amd64fre.vb_release.191206-1406)
 Operating System: Microsoft Windows Version 22H2 (OS Build 19045.3086)
 OSType: windows
 Architecture: x86_64
 CPUs: 8
 Total Memory: 31.88GiB
 Name: GEO-HjiS1MTZvp3
 ID: dae2db1c-70b5-49bf-ba37-476db299acd7
 Docker Root Dir: C:\ProgramData\Docker
 Debug Mode: true
  File Descriptors: -1
  Goroutines: 40
  System Time: 2023-07-07T13:57:03.2730227+02:00
  EventsListeners: 4
 Experimental: true
 ...
```

Running a linux container doesn't work, despite it clearly says "Experimental: true" above.

```
C:\work\build>docker run mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server:2019-latest --platform linux
Unable to find image 'mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server:2019-latest' locally
2019-latest: Pulling from mssql/server
docker: image operating system "linux" cannot be used on this platform: operating system is not supported.
See 'docker run --help'.
```

This is how it looks when it's working:

```
C:\Users\grap>docker info
Client:
 Context:    default
 Debug Mode: false
 Plugins:
  buildx: Build with BuildKit (Docker Inc., v0.6.3)
  compose: Docker Compose (Docker Inc., v2.0.0)
  scan: Docker Scan (Docker Inc., v0.8.0)

Server:
 Containers: 1
  Running: 1
  Paused: 0
  Stopped: 0
 Images: 33
 Server Version: 20.10.9
 Storage Driver: windowsfilter (windows) lcow (linux)
  Windows:
  LCOW:
 Logging Driver: json-file
 Plugins:
  Volume: local
  Network: ics internal l2bridge l2tunnel nat null overlay private transparent
  Log: awslogs etwlogs fluentd gcplogs gelf json-file local logentries splunk syslog
 Swarm: inactive
 Default Isolation: hyperv
 Kernel Version: 10.0 19044 (19041.1.amd64fre.vb_release.191206-1406)
 Operating System: Windows 10 Enterprise Version 2009 (OS Build 19044.3086)
 OSType: windows
 Architecture: x86_64
 CPUs: 12
 Total Memory: 31.78GiB
 Name: ...
 ID: TNQG:YHL6:UHXO:BR24:A4NC:4ECA:JTOW:SLMF:AYLF:TJFM:HC7R:LXDA
 Docker Root Dir: D:\ProgramData_Docker
 Debug Mode: false
 Registry: https://index.docker.io/v1/
 Labels:
 Experimental: true
 ...
```

The interesting part seems to be the line with `Storage Driver`. But how do I get both windows and lcow to work simultaneously again?

Answer (score 2):

According to [this](https://forums.docker.com/t/was-support-for-mixed-mode-windows-linux-containers-removed/136484), Docker Desktop 4.18 was the last version with Docker Engine 20.10, which supported that feature

Comment: Thanks for that link, but that still sounds like the behavior is a bug. Linux containers _do_ run on windows, and it seems they just removed a particular implementation for doing so.

Answer (score 0):

Steps that worked for me on Server 2019 and Windows 10.

```
wsl --install --no-distribution
shutdown -r -t 0
iex ((New-Object System.Net.WebClient).DownloadString('https://chocolatey.org/install.ps1')) | Out-Null
choco install docker-engine --version=20.10.24
```

if docker-engine install fails with the error
`Stop: System error 1317 has occurred. The upgrade of docker-engine was NOT successful.`
run `lusrmgr.msc` and add the current user to the `docker-users` group

```
[Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable("LCOW_SUPPORTED", "1", "Machine")
```

Add `"experimental": true` to `C:\ProgramData\docker\config\daemon.json`

```
restart-service docker
```

Comment: I might try this again, but I meanwhile changed my dependencies so I don't need to run both simultaneously.